# Vimscript function calls from terminal emulator

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim, terminal-emulator

I have Language server client ([vim-lsc](https://github.com/natebosch/vim-lsc)) installed as a plugin in neovim. This client interacts with a language server for couple of languages, like python or R, and provides features like autocomplete, variable renaming etc...

One feature I want to use is the code execution, in which case you can select the part of the code and then send it to the LSP server for evaluation and get the response for it. I can do a similar thing if I create a terminal emulator "term://python" and copy paste the code there, but in this way there are two "servers" running, one via the LSP server and other from the terminal, similar to what [vim-matlab](https://github.com/daeyun/vim-matlab) does.

I was hoping to be able to do both with just one instance of python or R or MATLAb running. If there is a way to send the typed "command" in the terminal emulator to the LSP server via the vim-lsc plugin, then the job can be done with just one instance running.

I also thought of making a vimscript which creates a buffer that emulates terminal (like how Conque or [vim-terminal](https://github.com/tc50cal/vim-terminal) do) and then capture and pass the commands via that script. Although, I was not able to figure out how those plugin made the prompt and command output non-modifiable but keeping the current typed command by the user modifiable.

My reason for preferring the LSP route and not opting for plugins like [vimterm](https://github.com/kanosuke/vimterm) is that they don't provide various features like autocomplete and refactoring.

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I would like to clarify that as of now I don't think vim-lsc has the capability to send the executeCommand request. I wrote a small vimscript (sepatate code)  which is able to do that. I plan to submit a pull-request in time and have the feature available in vim-lsc, hence the inclusion of vim-lsc in the description. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If it's part of the LSP protocol, and you can indeed send the code to the LSP server for execution, then it's not one that vim-lsc has implemented; I can't find it in the helpfile. Best thing you can do is search on the issue page and/or post about the feature yourself.